# PHP video Uploaded file shows Black screen while playing

Tags: php, file, upload

I am trying to upload video file(Mp4) through 3.php and 4.php. The vidio file uploaded is stored in /upload directory correctly with accurate size.

My problem is that when I tried to play the uploaded file with my php program 5.php it shows black screen playing without any picture or voice.

I had check The original file which is fine.

## 3.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="4.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## 4.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp4");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

## 5.php

```
<?php 

$filename = "04072012033.mp4";   // This is uploaded finename.
?>
<div class="form-group">
        <video width="300" controls>
            <source src="./upload/<?php echo $filename; ?>" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="./upload/<?php echo $filename; ?>" type="video/webm">
            <source src="./upload/<?php echo $filename; ?>" type="video/ogg">

        </video>
    </div>
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Have you tried to copy file manually to the upload location and play it from there? It is possible that the issue is not in the file. There are some limitation on video playback. it should be on the same domain and so on. This could be the issue. Google for CORS. It will give you some information.

Comment: Thanks For the reply.

Comment: Thanks For the reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I had tried copying file directly to uploaded location. It is playing through VLC player but not from PHP file. 
I tried to upload ome more files and found that SampleVideo_360x240_1mb.mp4 and SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb are played from both VLC player and pfp file 

but SampleVideo_640x360_1mb is able to play from VLC but not from the php file.

can it be resolution Problem ? I don't know ?

Thanks.

Comment: it could be anything. Different video encoding, different file format etc. Read more about browser video compatibility.

Comment: I had done lot of research and found that the file with codec mp4v is not played. I had tried to add codec in <video tag also> like <source src="./upload/<?php echo $filename; ?>" type="video/mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="mp4v.20.240, mp4a.40.2"'> but still not working.  can pl. guide me where and what i m mising ? thanks.

Comment: It is about browser supporting the video format. You can do nothing with it.